# Top activity must be located out of the custom package?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need some help.
Top activity must be located out of the custom package?
In this case, the MainActivity should be out of the custom package?
activity is a custom package name.

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: you have to change the path of MainActivity to Package Path of App.

Comment: creating separate package is good coding practice, if your main activity in custom package then give the path for set in manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activities need to be in the package namespace of the app, but can be in any sub package structure.